# How to prepare state for several JUnit tests only once

Tags: junit

I need to test a program that first preprocesses some data and then computes several different results using this preprocessed data -- it makes sense to write separate test for each computation.

Official JUnit policy seems to be that I should run preprocessing before each computation test.
How can I set up my test so that I could run the preparation only once (it's quite slow) before running remaining tests?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the annotation [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) to annotate the method which will be run once before all test methods.

Comment: Thanks! I think I should start reading manuals after all :p. JUnit main "tutorial" gave me impression that this kind of preparation is not directly supported.

Comment: @BeforeClass requires a static method, requiring static fields.  This is not necessarily evil, but it could affect your tests.